# Spark 3.0 JdbcRDD Java - Issue in specifying lowerBound and upperBound for views with no ID column

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 3.0, in my Java program I am querying data from views which are in Oracle DB. I used the Java API JdbcRDD to query the views.
The problem I have is that the view doesn't contain any ID or timestamp columns. So, I am unable to construct my SQL query with lowerBound and upperBound values.
Please find below the example query I need to run in Spark. Here exp_stg.usr and exp_stg.prtcpnt are the two views exposed to me.

```
"SELECT a.participant, 
       a.desc, 
       b.firstname, 
       b.lastname, 
       b.dept, 
       b.telno, 
       b.emailaddr
FROM   usr_stg.prtcpnt a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN usr_stg.usr b 
                    ON a.participant = b.participant 
WHERE  a.class = 'SpSession' "
```

I tried using temp tables in spark and join, but the query performance is bad as there are around ~13,000,000 rows in each view. Hence I tried to use the join query in the Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome the constraint using ROWNUM in the query. Using ROWNUM as the lowerBound and upperBound I am now able to get the data using JdbcRDD.
`

```
SELECT ROWNUM as id, a.participant, 
       a.desc, 
       b.firstname, 
       b.lastname, 
       b.dept, 
       b.telno, 
       b.emailaddr
FROM   usr_stg.prtcpnt a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN usr_stg.usr b 
                    ON a.participant = b.participant 
WHERE  a.class = 'SpSession' and ?<=ROWNUM and ROWNUM<=?"`
```

Answer (score 0):

- rownum is similar to limit - will not help as partition column
- Use an integer column that is already part of source rdbms table
- If no integer column at source then derive using the rdbms native functions
  for instance ORA_HASH of oracle

SELECT * FROM   TRANSACTION_TBL where  ?<= MOD(ORA_HASH(RECID),9) and MOD(ORA_HASH(RECID),9) <=?

- 0 // lowerBound
- 8 // upperBound
- 9 // numPartitions